# How can I leave a function? Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey I have an ElevatedButton with an onPressed. Inside the onPressed are some if-statements that ensure that everything is correct and afterwards I want to push these information to firebase. How can I leave the onPressed function if a condition is not fulfilled? I tried return and return null, return 0 but my App is just freezing.

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      if (date != null) {
        print(date);
      } else {
        dialog.showAlertDialog(context, 'Oops', 'You didn\'t choose a date!');
        return;
      }

      if (time != null) {
        print(time);
      } else {
        dialog.showAlertDialog(context, 'Oops', 'You didn\'t choose a time!');
        return 0;
      }

      if(combinedDateAndTime.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
        dialog.showAlertDialog(context, 'Oops', 'Your date and time is in the past');
        return null;
      }
      
      _firestore.collection('foo').add({
        'dateTime': combinedDateAndTime,
      });
    },
    style: raisedButtonStyle,
    ),
  ),
```

I just couldn't figure out how to leave the function. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is that define a boolean variable and check if it is true then firestore.collection called, somthing like this :

```
bool var = true;

if (date != null) {
    print(date);
  } else {
    dialog.showAlertDialog(context, 'Oops', 'You didn\'t choose a date!');
    var = false;
  }

  if (time != null) {
    print(time);
  } else {
    dialog.showAlertDialog(context, 'Oops', 'You didn\'t choose a time!');
    var = false;
  }

  if(combinedDateAndTime.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
    dialog.showAlertDialog(context, 'Oops', 'Your date and time is in the past');
    var = false;
  }

  if (var == true){

  _firestore.collection('foo').add({
    'dateTime': combinedDateAndTime,
  });
  }
```